# Over lapping in SQL

Tags: sql, join, vertica

I have a table with following data:

```
User#       App
1       A
1       B
2       A   
2       B
3       A
```

I want to know overlapping between Apps by distinct Users, so my end result with look like this

```
App1  App2  DistinctUseroverlapped 
A     A     3
A     B     2
B     B     2
```

So what result means is there are 3 users using app A only , there are 2 users who use App A and App B both , and there are 2 users who use App B only.

Remember there lot of app and users how can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution starts by generating all possible pairs of applications that are of interest.  This is the `driver` subquery.

It then joins in the original data for each of the apps.

Finally, it uses `count(distinct)` to count the distinct users that match between the two lists.

```
select pairs.app1, pairs.app2,
       COUNT(distinct case when tleft.user = tright.user then tleft.user end) as NumCommonUsers
from (select t1.app as app1, t2.app as app2
      from (select distinct app
            from t
           ) t1 cross join
           (select distinct app
            from t
           ) t2
      where t1.app <= t2.app
     ) pairs left outer join
     t tleft
     on tleft.app = pairs.app1 left outer join
     t tright
     on tright.app = pairs.app2
group by pairs.app1, pairs.app2
```

You could move the conditional comparison in the `count` to the joins and just use `count(distinct)`:

```
select pairs.app1, pairs.app2,
       COUNT(distinct tleft.user) as NumCommonUsers
from (select t1.app as app1, t2.app as app2
      from (select distinct app
            from t
           ) t1 cross join
           (select distinct app
            from t
           ) t2
      where t1.app <= t2.app
     ) pairs left outer join
     t tleft
     on tleft.app = pairs.app1 left outer join
     t tright
     on tright.app = pairs.app2 and
        tright.user = tleft.user
group by pairs.app1, pairs.app2
```

I prefer the first method because it is more explicit on what is being counted.

This is standard SQL, so it should work on Vertica.

Answer (score 0):

this works in vertica 6

```
 with tab as 
    ( select 1 as user,'A' as App
    union  select 1 as user,'B' as App
    union select 2 as user,'A' as App
    union select 2 as user,'B' as App
    union select 3 as user,'A' as App
    )
    , apps as 
    ( select distinct App  from tab )
    select apps.app as APP1,tab.app as APP2 ,count(distinct tab.user) from tab,apps
    where tab.app>=apps.app
    group by 1,2
    order by 1
```